# Getting error code -99 in onScanFailed for Galaxy s4 with android 5.0.1

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-5.0-lollipop, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a ScanCallback which works great on most phones and sdks, but for 1 user who has Galaxy s4 with android 5.0.1 the scan is failing with error code -99. 
In the documentation I can clearly see there is only 4 valid status codes which are: 1,2,3,4, So status code -99 is not documented:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanCallback.html#onScanFailed(int)

Here is my code:

```
private final ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
        BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();
        checkDevice(device);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBatchScanResults(List< ScanResult > results) {
        super.onBatchScanResults(results);
        checkResults(results);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
        super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
        Logger.d("scanning devices failed , error code: " + errorCode);
    }
};
```

And the startScan function:

```
public void startScan() {
    ScanSettings scanSettings = new ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY).build();
    ScanFilter scanFilters = new ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(BLEManager.BLE_DEVICE_SERVICE_UUID), new ParcelUuid(BLE_SERVICE_FILTER_MASK)).build();
    mAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().startScan(Arrays.asList(scanFilters), scanSettings, mScanCallback);
}
```

I look all over to find other status codes without any luck. 
Any idea?

Comment: solved by using nordic scanner: https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-Scanner-Compat-Library

Comment: how is this solved by using a library?